# how do I insert a carriage return in a string \r\n does not work

Tags: ruby, angularjs, carriage-return

I am adding `\r\n` to strings and expecting to see in the output a carriage return.

For example:

```
   %li{'ng-repeat'=> 'chat in chats track by $index', 'ng-class'=> 'mainCtrl.getMessageStyle(chat)'} 
        {{chat.user}}: {{chat.message}}
```

The above is using angular to print the message string.

My route has the following:

```
message:return_message['bot_response']}.to_json
```

`return_message['bot_response'] = "sometstuff \r\n more stuff \r\n"`

However, I am not seeing a carriage return.  the `\r\n` disappear but no carriage return.

Ditto when the same string is injected into the body of an email.

Comment: you display it on a page? have you tried <br>?

Comment: You appear to expect carriage return in rendered html. Browsers treats `\r\n` as space, to have a real line feed you need to print out `<br>` tag.

Comment: Wrapping your output in a <pre> tag will preserve the formatting in html.

Comment: <br/> gets rendered on the page

Answer (score 0):

```
return_message['bot_response'] = "sometstuff \r\n more stuff \r\n".replace('\r\n','<br />');
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: <br/> when added to the string just gets output